# Referencing between sheets with formulas generated in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to populate a cell with a basic formula that references both the current worksheet and another worksheet.

The formula I am trying to input into a cell is basically... `='Sheet2'A(j) / B(i)` with the following code:

```
For i = 1 To 5
    For j = 1 To 5
        With shOut.Cells(i,j)
            .formula = "='Sheet2'" & Cells(j,1)).Address & "/" & Cells(i,2).Address
        End With
    Next j
Next i
```

The part I am having trouble with is the sheet referencing at the start; when I run this in a `.formula`, it triggers an error.

However, when I remove the '=' sign and make it output in a `.Value`, it prints out what I want it to, except it's not a formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You have a `)` too much in your line that begins with `.formula`.
2. You are missing the `!` after the sheet:

   ```
   .formula = "=Sheet2!" & Cells(j,1).Address & "/" & Cells(i,2).Address
   ```

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't have to construct the address of any range yourself - you'll only leave yourself open to potential problems by doing so.

For example, in cularis' (perfectly good) answer, there are no single-quotes around the sheet name. They're not required in this case, but if the sheet name had a space in it, then you *do* need the quotes. (My point is that you shouldn't have to know - and cater for - all this stuff yourself).

Instead, you can specify `External:=True` in the call to `Address()`, which will give you an address that includes the sheet name. I'd do something like this:

```
Dim oWorksheet1 As Worksheet
Dim oWorksheet2 As Worksheet

...

.Formula = "=" & oWorksheet1.Cells(j,1).Address(External:=True) & "/" & oWorksheet2.Cells(i,2).Address(External:=True)
```

Note that in your case you probably only need to use the `External` parameter for one of the worksheets, but doing it that extra time won't hurt, as Excel will simplify the formula for you anyway.

Comment: Just a quick note, the general form for this should have an "=" at the beginning, so `target.formula = "=" & Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1").Address(External:=True)`